# How to create ZIP file for a list of "virtual files" and output to httpservletresponse

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, zip

My goal is to put multiple java.io.File objects into a zip file and print to HttpServletResponse for the user to download.

The files were created by the JAXB marshaller.  It's a java.io.File object, but it's not actually on the file system (it's only in memory), so I can't create a FileInputStream.

All resources I've seen use the OutputStream to print zip file contents.  But, all those resources use FileInputStream (which I can't use).

Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean it's a `java.io.File`? A `File` object is just a fancy address object; it doesn't carry any file content. Where are your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I'm an idiot :)  The file that was being "created" was saving to invalid path and swallowing the exception, so I thought it was being "created" ok.  When I tried to to instantiate a new FileInputStream, however, it complained that file didn't exist (rightly so).  I had a brainfart and assumed that the java.io.File object actually contained file information in it somewhere.  But as erickson pointed out, that was false.

Thanks Ralph for the code, I used it after I solved the invalid pathing issue.

My code:

```
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

File file;
InputStream in;
// Loop through entities
for (TitleProductAccountApproval tpAccountApproval : tpAccountApprovals) {
    // Generate the file    
    file = xmlManager.getXML(
        tpAccountApproval.getTitleProduct().getTitleProductId(), 
        tpAccountApproval.getAccount().getAccountId(), 
        username);

    // Write to zip file
    in = new FileInputStream(file);
    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));

    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }

    out.closeEntry();
    in.close();
}

out.close();
```

Comment: Invalide pathing issue? - what do you mean - is there a serios bug in the code of my answer?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) library, it provides the functionality you need.

Of course "erickson" is right with his comment to your question. You will need the file content and not the `java.io.File` object. In my example I assume that you have a method
`byte[] getTheContentFormSomewhere(int fileNummer)` which returns the file content (in memory) for the fileNummer-th file. -- Of course this function is poor design, but it is only for illustration.

It should work a bit like this:

```
void compress(final OutputStream out) {
  ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(out);
  zipOutputStream.setLevel(ZipOutputStream.STORED);

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     //of course you need the file content of the i-th file
     byte[] oneFileContent = getTheContentFormSomewhere(i);
     addOneFileToZipArchive(zipOutputStream, "file"+i+"."txt", oneFileContent);
  }

  zipOutputStream.close();
}

void addOneFileToZipArchive(final ZipOutputStream zipStream,
          String fileName,
          byte[] content) {
    ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = new ZipArchiveEntry(fileName);
    zipStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    zipStream.write(pdfBytes);
    zipStream.closeEntry();
}
```

Snipets of your http controller:

```
HttpServletResponse response
...
  response.setContentType("application/zip");
  response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"compress.zip\"");
  response.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
  ByteArrayOutputStream outputBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  compress(outputBuffer);
  response.getOutputStream().write(outputBuffer.toByteArray());
  response.getOutputStream().flush();
  outputBuffer.close();
```