# Zipping multiple files on server side and then Downloading them

Tags: java, zip, download

I have a requirement to download multiple files from server and zip them into one file. So that user will have to deal with only one file while downloading.

I need in Java/JSP code or Javascript

Comment: same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685476/how-to-create-zip-file-for-a-list-of-virtual-files-and-output-to-httpservletres

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy.

First, allow the user to choose files (if the application requires them to do so).
Then on clicking download create a zipped file dynamically and add all chosen files. Allow the user to download this file.

I'd used [Zip functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) in PHP for similar functionality in the past.

You can refer [Compressing and Decompressing data using Java APIs](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) from Sun Developers Network (SDN) on Oracle website.

Comment: Thanks Vikram... I checked the java API. It helped. :-)